# Creating fractal image in a plot MATLAB but the plot is empty

Tags: image, matlab, plot, fractals

I am writing a function to create a fractal image in a plot. When I run my code, a plot pops up but it is empty. I think the issues lies somewhere in my if/elseif statements, but I am having a hard time finding it. My code is:

```
function [] = fractal(x, y, N)
close all
start = [x, y];
X = zeros(N+1,1);
Y = zeros(N+1,1);
X = start;
hold on
for i = 1:N
prob = rand;
if prob >= 0.01
    X(i+1,:) = 0;
    Y(i+1,:) = 0.16*y(1);
elseif prob == 0.02:0.86
    X(i+1,:) = (0.85*x(i))-(0.04*y(i));
    Y(i+1,:) = (-0.04*x(i))+(0.85*y(i))+1.6;
elseif prob == 0.87:0.94
    X(i+1,:) = (0.2*x(i))-(0.26*y(i));
    Y(i+1,:) = (0.23*x(i))+(0.22*y(i))+1.6;
elseif prob == 0.95:1.0
    X(i+1,:) = (-0.15*x(i))+(0.28*y(i));
    Y(i+1,:) = (0.26*x(i))+(0.24*y(i))+0.44;
plot(X(i,:),Y(i,:),'.','Markersize',1)
axis equal 
    end
end
end
```

When I run my code with

```
>> fractal(1,1,1000)
```

... a plot comes up but it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup... it's your `if` statements, but there are more issues with your code though but we will tackle those later.  Let's first address your `if` statements.  If you want to compare in a range of values for examples, you need use the AND (`&&`) statement.  In addition, you should place your `plot` code outside of any `if/elseif/else` statement. You currently have it inside your last `elseif` statement so `plot` will only run if the last condition is satisfied.

To be explicit, if you wish to compare if a value is in between a certain range, do something like:

```
if (prob >= a && prob < b)
```

and for `elseif`:

```
elseif (prob >= a && prob < b)
```

`a` and `b` are the lower and upper limits of what you want to compare.  This **includes** `a` but **excludes** `b` in the comparison.

I also have a several comments and recommendations with your current code in order to get this to work:

1. You run your function with a single `x` and `y` value, but you are trying to access this `x` and `y` in your `for` loop as if these were arrays.  I'm assuming this is **recursive** in nature so you need to actually use `X` and `Y` in your `if/else` conditions instead of `x` and `y`.
2. Since you are using single values, it is superfluous to use `:` to access the second dimension.  Just leave that out.
3. You create `X` and `Y` but then overwrite `X` to be the starting location as a 2D array... I think you meant to replace `X` and `Y`'s first element with the starting location instead.
4. Your first `if` statement I think is incorrect. You'd want to access `Y(i)` not `Y(1)` no?... given the behaviour of your code thus far.
5. Your first condition will definitely mess things up for you.  This is saying that as long as the value is greater than or equal to 0.01, execute that statement.  Otherwise, try and execute the other conditions which may in fact never work because you are looking for values that are greater than 0.01 where the first condition already handles that for you.  I assume you meant to check if it was **less** than 0.01 instead.
6. Doing `value comparecondition array` in MATLAB means that this statement is true provided that **any one of the values in array** matches the condition provided by `value`.  This will have unintended side effects with your current code.
7. Make sure that your ranges covered for each `if` statement are continuous (i.e. no gaps or disconnects between ranges).  Right now, you are checking for values in 0.01 intervals.  `rand` generates random values between 0 and 1 exclusive.  What if you had a value of 0.15?  None of your `if` conditions handle this so you need to use what I talked about above.
8. You are most likely getting a blank plot because your `MarkerSize` attribute is very small.... you set it to 1 pixel.  Unless you have super human vision, you can't really visualize this.  Make the `MarkerSize` larger.
9. Use `drawnow;` after you `plot` to immediately update the results to screen.

---

Therefore, with refactoring your code, you should make it look something like this:

```
function [] = fractal(x, y, N)
close all
start = [x, y];
X = zeros(N+1,1);
Y = zeros(N+1,1);
%// Change - Initialize first elements of X and Y to be the starting positions
X(1) = start(1);
Y(1) = start(2);
hold on
for i = 1:N
    prob = rand;
    if prob <= 0.01 %// Change
        X(i+1) = 0;
        Y(i+1) = 0.16*Y(i); %// Change
    elseif (prob > 0.01 && prob <= 0.86) %// Change
        X(i+1) = (0.85*X(i))-(0.04*Y(i)); %// Change
        Y(i+1) = (-0.04*X(i))+(0.85*Y(i))+1.6; %// Change
    elseif (prob > 0.86 && prob <= 0.94) %// Change
        X(i+1) = (0.2*X(i))-(0.26*Y(i)); %// Change
        Y(i+1) = (0.23*X(i))+(0.22*Y(i))+1.6; %// Change
    elseif (prob > 0.94 && prob <= 1.0) %// Change
        X(i+1) = (-0.15*X(i))+(0.28*Y(i)); %// Change
        Y(i+1) = (0.26*X(i))+(0.24*Y(i))+0.44; %// Change
    end

    %// Change - move outside of if/else blocks
    %// Also make marker size larger
    plot(X(i),Y(i),'.','Markersize',18); %// Change
    axis equal 

    %// Add just for kicks
    drawnow;
end

end
```

I now get this figure when I do `fractal(1,1,1000)`:

[image]

.... cool fractal btw!

Comment: Why do you double-check for `prob <relation> <number>`? If the code reaches line, say, `elseif (prob>0.86...` it is sure, that `prob>0.86`, because the `elseif` statement above would be evaluated and loop advanced to next iteration. I'd use `if prob<0.01` and `elseif prob<0.86` statements.

Comment: @Crowley That's true, but I like to be explicit.

Comment: X can be defined also by: `X=[x;zeros(N,1)];`.

Comment: @Crowley I appreciate your comments, but I like to leave my code the way it is. Thank you.

Comment: In a first case I tried to point that it's not mandatory to be explicit. In the second one that the declaration can be shorter and more error-proof. In both cases it doesnt worth separate answer.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you so much! This was extremely helpful

Comment: @Olivia You're very welcome. Let me know if there's anything else you need... otherwise, consider accepting my answer to let the SO community know you no longer need help.  Thanks!

Comment: I just have one last question, is there any way to speed up the running process? I thought that by preallocating the matrices my program would run a lot quicker than it is.

Comment: @Olivia The drawing is what is slowing you down.  If you like, you can wait until all of the points are generated, **then** draw the entire fractal in one shot.  If you want to do that, move the `plot`, `axis equal` and `drawnow` commands outside of the loop and place at the end of the code, then change the `plot` to `plot(X, Y, '.', 'MarkerSize', 18);`  However, I'm not sure if you want to visualize at each point or wait to see what the fractal looks like at the end.  If you want to do this at each point, there's nothing more you can do other than wait until `plot` finishes with each point.

Comment: @rayryeng I see! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @rayryeng if you could also please place more spaces in your code so it would be easier to read that would be great, thanks

Comment: @excaza For sure. I will edit my post because it doesnt worth separate answer.